# AttributeError: module 'shodan' has no attribute 'Shodan'

Tags: python, shodan

I need to perform a BULK whois query using shodan API.

I came across this code

```
import shodan
api = shodan.Shodan('inserted my API-KEY- within single quotes')
info = api.host('8.8.8.8')
```

After running the module i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/PIPY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/dam.py", line 1, in 
>   import shodan
>   File "C:/Users/PIPY/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37\shodan.py", line 2, in 
>   api = shodan.Shodan('the above insereted API KEY')
>   AttributeError: module 'shodan' has no attribute 'Shodan'

I'm learning python and have limited scripting/programming experience.

Could you please help me out?

Cheers

Comment: How did you install the `shodan` library?

Comment: in the comand prompt I have used :

pip install shodan then
shodan  init "my api key"

and the o/p was " successfully initializes"

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have `dam.py` and `shodan.py` – Python defaults to importing from the module directory, so the installed `shodan` package gets masked.

Try renaming `shodan.py` to e.g. `shodan_test.py` (and of course fixing up any imports, etc.).

Comment: I have renamed the file and now I have the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shodan'.

I have tried to install it again but gives me a list of "Requirement already satisfied:" messages

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by re-installing the shodan module under the C:\Users\PIPY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install shodan

Thank you for the help AKX.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but after renaming my file as something different than shodan.py, I had to also delete the compiled class shodan.pyc to avoid the error.

Also, if you have more than one version of python installed, i.e. python2 and python3, use

`python -m pip install shodan` instead of `pip install shodan`, to ensure that you are installing the library in the same version of shodan that you are using to execute your script.

If you are executing your script with `python3 shodan_test.py` then use `python3 -m pip install shodan`